# Need a way to test SSH with a timeout

Tags: python, ssh

This is my current code to test if a host is SSH-able. It works just fine when the host is up with or without SSH service running. However, it seems to just hang when the host crashes, which is the unique usecase that I need to depend on it giving me a quick True/False response. Due to OS and other dependencies, we need to keep the Python version to 2.6 for now. So I need a way to get this function to work and with a timeout of 1-2s.

```
import commands

def test_ssh(host):
    output = commands.getstatusoutput("ssh " + host + " hostname")
    if output[0] == 0:
        return True
    else:
        print(host + " not accessible via SSH!")
        return False
```

Comment: Does `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 ...` work?

Comment: I'll give it a try. The flag works just fine, and I added BatchMode per suggestion below. However, I am unable to reproduce the state the server was in when it had crashed on demand so I cannot say for sure until it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if it is actually a connect timeout, or if it can connect, but the server is accepting the connection and doesn't send anything.

If you were to use telnet to manually test, telnet  22 and see if you get a response from the server at all, you should see something like this if it connects:

```
$ telnet localhost 22
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
```

If it connects and you don't get any response, then I think you will have to try a test using sockets in python.

You can find info here: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Comment: I got the function working with socket. Since I cannot reproduce the state of the server on demand. I am unable to determine if this is guarantee to work given the state it may be in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that an SSH connection (including authentication) can be established correctly, the best way probably is to connect in batch mode with a small timeout (`-o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=2`).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll give it a try. The flags works as expected, though I will only know for sure if it works given the server had crashed the next time it happens.

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap your call to `ssh` into `timelimit` so it gets cancelled after a certain timeout if it does not finish on time.

- homepage: http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/
- manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/timelimit.1.html